# f4 Immigrant visa for fiji citizen for ageout children for 23 year old and 26 years

Tags: usa

Hi my dad received the approved visa petition from NVC stating we should start filling up the forms and submitting all the financial documents. In that letter mine(23 years) and my brother(26 years) name are there. We have paid the fees for all 4 of us and NVC has also sent us documentary qualified message and now awaiting for interview. I would just like to know whether mine and my bro name will appear on appointment letter and if does will we get the visa or will we be put on administrative process as we are above 21. thanks in advance